# deleting row from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio

I have 2 tables MachineGroups and Machines. MachineGroups has columns:

```
MachinegroupID
MachineGroupName
MachineGroupDesc
```

And Machines has columns:

```
MachineGroupID (FK)
MachineID
MachineName
Machinedesc
```

Now I want to delete a machinegroup but not the ones that have machines in it.

```
DELETE FROM MachineGroups
 WHERE MachineGroupID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT MachineGroupID FROM Machines)
```

This will delete all the rows in the gridview which have no. of machines= 0
What i want is to delete only the row whose delete link is clicked...

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="1" CellSpacing="2"
    DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None"
     Width="100%" ondatabound="GridView1_DataBound1"
    onrowdatabound="GridView1_RowDataBound1">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#D0D8E8" ForeColor="#333333" Height="35px" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MachineGroupID" HeaderText="MachineGroupID" 
            InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="MachineGroupID" 
            Visible="False" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MachineGroupName" HeaderText="MachineGroupName" 
            SortExpression="MachineGroupName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MachineGroupDesc" HeaderText="MachineGroupDesc" 
            SortExpression="MachineGroupDesc" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="TimeAdded" HeaderText="TimeAdded" 
            SortExpression="TimeAdded" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CanBeDeleted" SortExpression="CanBeDeleted" 
            Visible="False">
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"
                    Checked='<%# Bind("CanBeDeleted") %>' />
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"
                    Checked='<%# Bind("CanBeDeleted") %>' Enabled="false" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="No. of PCs" HeaderText="No. of PCs" ReadOnly="True"
            SortExpression="No. of PCs" />
        <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False"
                    CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete"></asp:LinkButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>


<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"         ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SumooHAgentDBConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT MachineGroups.MachineGroupID, MachineGroups.MachineGroupName, MachineGroups.MachineGroupDesc, MachineGroups.TimeAdded, MachineGroups.CanBeDeleted, COUNT(Machines.MachineName) AS 'No. of PCs' FROM MachineGroups FULL OUTER JOIN Machines ON Machines.MachineGroupID = MachineGroups.MachineGroupID GROUP BY MachineGroups.MachineGroupID, MachineGroups.MachineGroupName, MachineGroups.MachineGroupDesc, MachineGroups.TimeAdded, MachineGroups.CanBeDeleted" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM MachineGroups
 WHERE MachineGroupID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT MachineGroupID FROM Machines)">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_MachineGroupID" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_MachineGroupName" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_MachineGroupDesc" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_CanBeDeleted" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="original_TimeAdded" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: @unknown: you need to learn how to properly format XML and code snippets! Highlight the rows in question and then click on the "code" button (010 101) on the edit toolbar, or press Ctrl-K on your keyboard - only then will the code show up properly and be visible for others to answer your question!

Comment: thanks.. i remember it next time

Answer (score 1):

Not tested, but the direction should be right:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SumooHAgentDBConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT MachineGroups.MachineGroupID, MachineGroups.MachineGroupName, MachineGroups.MachineGroupDesc, MachineGroups.TimeAdded, MachineGroups.CanBeDeleted, COUNT(Machines.MachineName) AS 'No. of PCs' FROM MachineGroups FULL OUTER JOIN Machines ON Machines.MachineGroupID = MachineGroups.MachineGroupID GROUP BY MachineGroups.MachineGroupID, MachineGroups.MachineGroupName, MachineGroups.MachineGroupDesc, MachineGroups.TimeAdded, MachineGroups.CanBeDeleted" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM MachineGroups WHERE MachineGroupID = @MachineGroupID">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="MachineGroupID" />
    </DeleteParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```