# delete multiple row using checkbox in gridview ...i am using Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework

I have a requirement where I want to delete multiple row by placing check-box in each row
I want to place only single button for deleting multiple row in a gridview....

I am using this code but it is not working ...

```
EmployeeModel.EmployeeEntities obj=new EmployeeModel.EmployeeEntities();
foreach(GridViewRow row in grdVw.Rows)
{
   if ((row.FindControl("chkBox1") as CheckBox).Checked)  
   {
     string id=grdVw.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
     int a=int.Parse(id);
     var result = from n in obj.Emps where n.Ecode == a select n;

     obj.DeleteObject(result.First());
   }
}
obj.SaveChanges();
```

Here is the code for declaring my `GridView`:

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdVw" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ToolTip="Employee Details" DataKeyNames="Ecode"> 
    <Columns> 
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="select"> 
            <ItemTemplate> 
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox1" runat="server" /> 
            </ItemTemplate> 
        </asp:TemplateField> 
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="EmpCode" DataField="Ecode" /> 
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="EmpName" DataField="Ename" /> 
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Address" DataField="Address" /> 
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="City" DataField="city" /> 
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="EmailId" DataField="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="DOB" DataField="DOB" /> 
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="JoinDate" DataField="joinDate" /> 
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Salary" DataField="Salary" /> 
    </Columns> 
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Comment: no i am not getting any error...

Comment: acctually it not entering in if condition it is always going out of if....

Comment: Can you post the markup for your `GridView`?

Comment: <asp:GridView ID="grdVw" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ToolTip="Employee Details" DataKeyNames="Ecode">
    <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="select">
    <ItemTemplate>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBox1" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="EmpCode" DataField="Ecode" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="EmpName" DataField="Ename" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Address" DataField="Address" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="City" DataField="city" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="EmailId" DataField="Email" />

Comment: <asp:BoundField HeaderText="DOB" DataField="DOB" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="JoinDate" DataField="joinDate" />
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Salary" DataField="Salary" />
    </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

Comment: go to the on this link it will help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1485570/deleting-row-from-gridview?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify which cell contains the checkbox.
Change the code for:

```
row.Cells[/*index of the cell*/].FindControl("chkBox1")
```

Comment: it is first column so i m using [0] but it is not working fals

Comment: Could you post the ASPX pls? Theres something else wrong. My awnsear was one point, maybe we have more.

Answer (score 2):

Your `if ((row.FindControl("chkBox1") as CheckBox).Checked)` condition is not true the first time though, because you are encountering the header row of your `GridView` in the first iteration of the loop through all of the rows in the grid, like this:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in grdVw.Rows)
```

You need to check the row type, like this:

```
EmployeeModel.EmployeeEntities obj=new EmployeeModel.EmployeeEntities();
foreach(GridViewRow row in grdVw.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if ((row.FindControl("chkBox1") as CheckBox).Checked)  
        {
            string id=grdVw.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
            int a=int.Parse(id);
            var result = from n in obj.Emps where n.Ecode == a select n;

            obj.DeleteObject(result.First());
        }
    }
}
obj.SaveChanges();
```

Note: Please read the [MSDN documentation for GridViewRow.RowType Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridviewrow.rowtype.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-3) for more information about the different types of rows in the `GridView`.

UPDATE:

Try binding your `GridView` only on non-postbacks (read: first time the page loads), like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Blcommon obj = new Blcommon(); 
        grdVw.DataSource = obj.GetEmployee(); 
        grdVw.DataBind();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Okay, then that must mean your check box values are getting trashed before your `if` condition is being evaluated, where does the `grdVw.DataSource` and `grdVw.DataBind` logic happen relative to the code you have posted?

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Blcommon obj = new Blcommon();
        grdVw.DataSource = obj.GetEmployee();
        grdVw.DataBind();
    }

Comment: @sanjeet put if(!IsPostback) before this databind... this is cleaning the selection.